# How to write riscv CSR in an assembly macro taking immediate values as parameters?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, riscv

I am trying to write a reuseable macro to configure some CSR's in assembly.

E.g

```
.macro initTrap entry, status, enable
    la          t0, entry
    csrw        mtvec, t0
    csrwi       mstatus, status
    csrwi       mie, enable
.endm
```

Then to use it (at least to test):

```
initTrap trap_entry, 0x0, 0x0
```

When compiling (assembling) I get the following errors:

```
start.S:179: Error: Instruction csrwi requires absolute expression
start.S:179: Error: Instruction csrwi requires absolute expression
start.S:179: Error: Instruction csrwi requires absolute expression
```

Is there a way to create a macro that passes immediate values in without getting this error? (I can't seem to find any documentation on risc-v assembly macros beyond the ASM programming guide, which is how I got this far)

Comment: It seems the immediate value is not the problem, it is the arguments themself. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Answer: Need backslashes on argument uses.

```
.macro initTrap entry, status, enable
    la          t0, \entry
    csrw        mtvec, t0
    csrwi       mstatus, \status
    csrwi       mie, \enable
.endm
```